# Basic For Loop Logic Doesn't make sense to me

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I've been trying to learn Javascript for the longest time, and it is kind of frustrating.  I'm back to learning the basics again, and I was playing around with these `for` loops and arrays below.

Can someone please explain why the output of this code is `[1,2,3,4,5]` and not `[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]`?

```
var game1 = new Array();
for(i = 25; i > "love is like a river".length; i = i - 1) {
  console.log(game1.push(i)); 
}
```

Comment: Uh, I'm getting the expected `[25, 24, 23, 22, 21]` as the result for `game1`?

Comment: @Bergi "..please explain why the **output** of this code..". They are not talking about the value of `game1`, but the output to the console. This code isn't displaying output as the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log(game1.push(i));
```

What this statement does is it prints to the console the index of the element being pushed. The result 1,2,3,4,5 is the length of the array.

What you want to code is:

```
var game1 = [];

for(i = 25; i > "love is like a river".length; i--){

console.log(i);
game1.push(i);
}
```

in the above example I switched the declaration of the array, because this is the most common way(this is not necessary).It will still work normally with your version of declaration. In the for loop I've switched

```
i = i - 1;
```

to shorthand version:

```
i-- or --i
```

which decrements ' i ' by 1. Also I've separated

```
console.log(i) and game1.push(i) to be separate
```

this will print out the result of ' i ' : 25,24,23,22,21
this is because the for loop does the action that the users defines at the end of the loop, so when the loop prints out 21 and pushes it to the array, it decrements to 20, at which the loop stops. The array will still have the numbers 25,24,23,22,21. but the console will not log it.

if you want the output you defined above you would have to:

```
var game1 = [];
for(i = 6;i >= 25; i++){
game1.push(i);
console.log(game1[i-6]);
}
```

in this you add ' i ' to game1 resulting in [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14...25] and you log the variable at the index of ' i - 6'. This will result in the number int he square brackets being "0,1,2,3,4,5" starting at 0 because that is where all arrays indexs start at.

Answer (score 3):

The length property returns the length of a string (number of characters). In this way `"love is like a river".length` gives 20. I think you mistook it as no. of words. The loop will then behave like

```
var game1 = new Array();
for(i = 25;i>20;i=i-1){
    console.log(game1.push(i));
}
```

To get your expected answer the code would be:

```
var game1 = new Array();
for(i = 25;i>"love is like a river".length;i=i-1){
  console.log(game1.push(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The `"love is like a river".length` is 20. So the loop is equivalent to this:

```
for(i = 25; i>20; i=i-1){

}
```

That being said, you have 5 calls of the console.log passing to it the following arguments one at each for step:

```
game1.push(25)
game1.push(24)
game1.push(23)
game1.push(22)
game1.push(21)
```

Not knowing exactly what `game1.push` does, it's hard to tell. However, supposing that `game1` is an array, you would get at each push the new length of the array.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array **and**
>   **returns the new length of the array**.

Comment: that was exactly what got me confused.  The game1.push(25) ended up being a 1 because that was the first position in the array, but I expected there to be the number 25 actually being pushed into the array.  What I liked about your answer the most was that it showed me how the MDN shows how the push() method adds one element to an array and returns the new length of the array.

Comment: In situations like this it's always good to sit for a moment and think what would be actually useful implementation of a function for instance. It's more of a general advice, if you think about it you won't be so surprised why some things are the way they are (not all obviously).

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the expected `[25, 24, 23, 22, 21]` as the result for `game1`!

The `1`, `2`, `3`, … you are seeing are the results of the [Array `push` calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) that you are logging, which yield the length of the array each time.

Comment: Yes, my goal was to get 6-25 into the array. But where are you seeing the expected 25-21?

Answer (score 2):

`"love is like a river".length` is `20`, so you will start from `i=25` until `i=21`.

`[1,2,3,4,5]` represents the `length` of `game1` for each loop.

To see the `game1` value:

```
for(i=0; i<game1.length; i++) {
 console.log(game1[i]);
}
```

Result: `[25,24,23,22,21]`

Answer (score 1):

Lets start by breaking down your code, beginning with the **`new Array()`** *constructor* that you stored in the *variable* **game1**.

```
var game1 = new Array();
```

At this point, all you have is an **empty** *array*, which has been stored in a *variable* to be used at a later time.  Incidentally, this is the equivalent of the *array literal*: **`var game1 = []`**.

Lets step through to the next portion of your code, which is a **`for()`** loop:

**`for (i = 25; i > "love is like a river".length; i--) {}`**

This loop initializes at the **upper bound of 25** and decrements down to a **lower bound bound of 20** which is set by the **`length()`** *property* *condition* of the *string*.  Within this loop you have the *statement*:

`console.log(game1.push(i));`

The *method* **`push()`** adds an element or elements to the end of an *array* and *returns* the new *length* of the *array* to the stack.  This *method* relies on the *length property* to determine its injection point.  So, before the iteration, the **game1** *stack* is currently at **0** since you never populated the *array* with any values.  As you perform the iteration, **`push()`** *method* will add to the stack an *undefined* value on each step, there by increasing the *array* length by **1**.

This can be illustrated by calling your **game1** *variable* with a single numeric *argument*, which will set the initial size of the *array*.  Here is an example:

```js
var string = 'love is like a river';

var game1 = new Array(15);

for (i = 25; i > string.length; i--) {
  console.log(game1.push(1));
}
```

As you can see, I passed the numeric *argument* **15** to the **`new Array()`** *constructor* which set the initial **game1** *length* stack to 15.  Since we are decrementing from **25** *(i = 25)* to **20** *(string.length)* we iterate **5** times, producing the expected result: [16, 17, 18, 19, 20].

If you are looking for an outcome of [6, 7, 8,...,25] you can can adjust your **`for()`** *loop* **incrementing** as opposed to **decrementing** and set the intitializer to 6.  Here is what it will look like:

```js
var s = "love is like a river";

for (i = 6; i <= s.length + 5; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```